# .NET scope of static class using dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, static

I am creating an extensible windows service and I have a very important question regarding my approach.

I have a service that depends on a library (lets call it *db.dll*) that has a static class *Database*. 
The *Database* Class has methods to setup some configuration for db access and it holds it in static variables.

Then within the service I use dinamically loaded plugins (with the use of http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182970/A-Simple-Plug-In-Library-For-NET). All plugins depends on the *db.dll* too.

One of my plugins must access the database through some *db.dll* methods (from class *DbObject* which uses the configuration stored in *Database* class).

The question is, will the plugins use "the same" Database as the server or do I need the plugin to "initialize" the Database static class fields once again?

Also I know I could modify my *Database* class to become a singleton instead of making it static and pass it to plugin, but I would rather avoid this, therefore I'd really appreciate answers only related to my questions directly.

Comment: if the plugins have a reference to `db.dll`, you shouldn't have to.

Comment: Alright, I shouldn't, but I "may", that's the problem really :) If there will be no conclusive answer I'll go for testing it myself, but I just wanted to avoid it, since debugging it to check may take a while.

Comment: By the way @DanielA.White let me ask you another question. If all plugins depends on *db.dll* and my windows service does also then should I also include *db.dll* in plugins folder or there is no need for that?

Comment: @user1970395 There should be no need to do that, no. The dlls are loaded into the application domain.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I didn't get the conclusive answer (in case "shouldn't" means "definitely no" forgive me, I must have misunderstood then. Anyway, I did tests, debugging my windows service and it seems correct. my plugins are in scope of my static class. Also there is no need to put db.dll any place other than main executable folder. Thanks!